# Finding all derivatives of a Polynomial at a given point

Tags: derivatives, polynomials

Given a Polynomial of n degree in its coefficient representation.

$P_n (x)$ = $[a_0, a_1, a_2 ... a_n]$

How can I compute all derivatives of $P_n(x)$ at a point $c$

i.e I want to compute $P^{\prime}_n(c), P^{\prime \prime}_n(c), P^{\prime \prime \prime}_n(c) ...... P^{n}_n(c)$

I am writing a program to do this. Computing individual derivatives has a complexity of range $O(n^2)$. Is there any better way?

Comment: Just to be sure : do you mean that computing the $n$ derivatives have a complexity of $O(n^2)$ ?

Comment: Yes, I meant calculating n derivatives @charMD

Answer (score 0):

You can do so in $O\big(n \mathrm{ln}(n) \big)$ : see [Polynomials and FFT](http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~csli/graduate/algorithms/book6/chap32.htm) (Problem 32-3 at the end of the page).

The idea is to change the basis : if we know how to write $P(X) = \sum \limits_{k=0}^n b_k (X-c)^k$, we can get the derivatives at $c$ (they are $k!b_k$), so we can get them in $O(n)$.

Now if we denote $\omega = e^{\frac{2i\pi}{n+1}}$, if I am not mistaken, $b_k = \frac{1}{n+1} \sum \limits_{r=0}^n P(c+\omega^r) \omega^{-rk}$. Now if we already have computed the $P(c+\omega^k)$ for $0 \le k \le n$, it is well known that the [Fast-Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) allows us to compute the $b_k$ in $O\big(n\mathrm{ln}(n) \big)$.

*Final step :* we must compute $P(c+\omega^k)$ for $0 \le k \le n$ with a complexity $O\big(n\mathrm{ln}(n) \big)$. We have $P(c+\omega^k)=\sum \limits_{r=0}^n \omega^{rk} \cdot \Big(\sum \limits_{j=0}^{n-r} \frac{a_{j+r} (j+r)! c^j}{r!j!} \Big)$ (with the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)), and apparently you can compute all $P(c+\omega^k)$ in $O \big(n \mathrm{ln}(n) \big)$.